# using external javascript with html and change specific variable?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have 3 html files that will use same variable,same function in javascript **except** *query function*.

**Each html will query the data from different google sheet.**

now I'm using script inside html like this

```
<script>

google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['geochart']});

google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

function drawRegionsMap() { 

    var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RsugJPtz2EdHOLaiL0SvR9bh61H-vAgn9x1QBjIJ--c/edit?usp=sharing');

    query.send(handleQueryResponseTR);
}

function handleQueryResponseTR(response) {

    if (response.isError()) {
                    alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());

                    return;
        }

    var data = response.getDataTable();

    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);

    chart.draw(view,options);

    </script>
```

but I want to create **external script file** for all 3 html files because it use almost all the same variable/function.

the thing is, how can I do that with different data in query function?

Can I set new value(spreadsheet link) to **query** variable from external script in each html file?

anyone can help?

any example would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: pass a param location to `drawRegionsMap(location)` and use param in `google.visualization.Query(location)`. now you can call this from all three pages `drawRegionsMap(location1);  drawRegionsMap(location2); `...

Comment: @Anil thnks a lot!